# Installing Custom R package

Tags: r, rstudio

I was trying to install a custom R Package that has a bigmemory dependency . Learned that bigmemory is not available for windows . Referring many pages I tried to install bigmemory from source . I downloaded the .tar file that is available for linux from CRAN . But installing that returns Error: UNIX only package . I m using R Studio . Please Help !!!.

Comment: People have reported success with Virtualbox installation of Linux on Window machines.

Comment: I wanted pure windows

Answer (score 0):

Are you using UNIX or Windows? If the package said UNIX only, then you may try Linux to see if comparable, but not Windows.

Comment: I m using windows and I wanted to stay on windows .

Comment: Then it is clearly not available unless you want to modify the source code to make it work on windows.